# Bind view-model property setter to control method

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, mvvm, data-binding

I'm currently dealing with a rather MVVM-unfriendly custom control that exposes a lot of it's "properties" through plain methods instead of dependency properties, or requires the properties to be set by a method because additional parameters need to be passed.

Simple pseudo example:

```
class TextControl : CustomControl {
    void SetText(string text, int fontSize);
    string GetText(string defaultValue);   
}
```

Now I'd like to bind to the "Text" of the control, and just e.g. pass some defaults for the parameters, if needed. As for the "setter", I can just make an attached property and provide a callback which then invokes the `SetText()`, but what about the "getter"? Is there a clean way to handle this or is the only way to pass the view to the view-model?

Comment: What exactly are you trying to achieve? Binding to properties is not the end of the world. If the app works, then you are just refactoring for fun. If this is a third party control, then say so.

Comment: @ΩmegaMan Yes, it's indeed a 3rd-party control.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you can do is to create your own custom control which will simply encapsulate the control in question. That way you can expose MVVM'able dependency properties, but in the code behind it manipulates and tweaks the third party control as needed.

Answer (score 1):

You could create attached properties to provide bindings, these properties would internally manipulate the "unfriendly" control.

Info: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/desktop/wpf/advanced/attached-properties-overview?view=netframeworkdesktop-4.8

One potential advantage is that attached properties can be be used on more than one control; so if you happened to have a family of 3rd party controls which shared some attributes in common, you might be able to write one set of attached properties to be used on all of them.

Comment: As mentioned in my own question, I already tried with attached properties, however I'm not entirely sure how the getter of an attached property should work when I'm trying to get the value from the control the property is attached to, and not from the attached property itself.